# Javascript nested object access root level

Tags: javascript, object

I have a nested object in javascript like this one:

```
{
nameRoot: "my object",
sub: {
  nameSub: "my sub object"
}
}
```

I want to access nameRoot from a function defined in sub.

Using a function i would have defined something like:

```
var self = this;
```

and used self but how can I do this in a literal object?

Comment: I don't believe you can.  I don't know of the post off the top of my head, but I remember reading this on StackOverflow recently.  Can you define that object as a function, instead of an object literal?

Comment: You can’t. But an object is not without reference, so somewhere you must have a reference to the object you are in, no?

Comment: This is also the reason why nodes and such need to have an explicit reference back to `parentNode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code allows you to link to a parent element and avoid the parent showing up in a for-in loop.

```
var parent = { a: 1 };
var child = { b: 2 };

Object.defineProperty(
    child, 'parent', 
    { value: parent, 
      enumerable: false }
);

parent.child = child;

child.performAction = function() {
    console.log(this.parent.a) // 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the best way to do this is w/ function scope.

```
function myFunc(){
   this.nameRoot = "my object";
}
```

then you could do something like:

```
var func = new myFunc();
func.sub = new myFunc();
func.sub.nameRoot = "my sub object";
```

Obviously there are smarter ways to do it (e.g. pass the name through the function params) but this is the general pattern.

Comment: Question: _but how can I do this in a "literal object"_

Comment: You can't, that's why I said to do it the way I suggested.